# how to append side menu on single page on right side ionic?

Tags: angularjs, menu, ionic-framework

i have a mobile app which is having hamburger icon on the right side in only 2 pages , i want to include a aide menu only on those 2 pages only , how will i append that using ionic , i have taken blank app as a module to start upon ,kindly help.

here is my index.html

```
 <body ng-app="starter">
  <ion-nav-bar>
        <ion-nav-back-button class="button-clear">
        </ion-nav-back-button>

        <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
        <button class="ion-ios-search-strong button-clear search-icon"></button>
    </ion-nav-buttons>  

  </ion-nav-bar>
    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
  </body>
```

here is my app.js states

```
  $stateProvider
         // setup an abstract state for the tabs directive
           .state('login', {
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: 'login/login.html',
            controller: 'loginCtrl'
          })
           .state('home', {
                url: "/home",
                templateUrl: "home/home.html",
                controller:"homeCtrl"

          })
```

here is my page on which i want to show menu in right side:

```
<ion-view view-title="ASSET 1">
        <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
        <button class="ion-ios-search-strong button-clear search-icon"></button>
        <button class="ion-navicon button-clear hamburger-icon">
        </button>
        </ion-nav-buttons> 

<ion-view hide-nav-bar="false" class="ane" ng-controller="assetdetailCtrl">    
<ion-content>
hii there 

</ion-content>
```

here is menu.html:

```
<ion-side-menus enable-menu-with-back-views="false">
  <ion-side-menu-content>
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-balanced">
      <ion-nav-back-button>
      </ion-nav-back-button>

      <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
        <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="right">
        </button>
      </ion-nav-buttons>
    </ion-nav-bar>
    <ion-nav-view name="menuContent"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-side-menu-content>

  <ion-side-menu side="left">
    <ion-content>
      <ion-list>
        <ion-item nav-clear menu-close href="#/home/home">
          <i class="icon ion-home"></i> Início
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-side-menu>
</ion-side-menus>
```

Comment: Why not create a sample demo over here : http://play.ionic.io/app/413fb7e5232a